# Unable to successfully start the simplest Camel CDI route in Karaf 4.1.0 or ServiceMix 7.0.0 (Karaf 4.0.8)

Tags: apache-camel, cdi, karaf, pax

I've been trying without success to build and deploy a simple route with Camel and CDI.  I'm focused on deploying to ServiceMix 7.0.0, but have also tried this on a plane jane Karaf 4.1.0 and get precisely the same results.

I built a very simple route based on the Camel CDI examples from both 2.16.4 and 2.18.2.  I'm excluding some of the testing stuff for now, just trying to get things to work when I deploy it in Karaf/ServiceMix.

My RouteBuilder is:

```
public class DemoRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoRouteBuilder.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        log.info("Starting demo CDI route");
        from("timer://cdiTimer?period=5000")
          .routeId("com.omniprise.demo.cdi.route")
          .to("log:com.omniprise..demo.cdi.context")
          .to("mock:end");
    }
}
```

I also have the requisite  and  content in my POM:

```
            <Export-Package>com.omniprise.demo.cdi.builder</Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
            <Require-Capability>
              osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=pax.cdi)",
              org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extension; filter:="(extension=camel-cdi-extension)"
            </Require-Capability>
```

Complete Java and POM code is at the end of the question.

Note that the camel-cdi feature will fail to install on ServiceMix 7.0.0 due to dependency conflicts:

- ServiceMix 7.0.0 is using Camel 2.16.4
- camel-cdi in 2.16.4 is looking for DeltaSpike [1.5.0,2.0)
- camel-cdi in 2.16.4 is looking for pax-cdi 1.0.0.RC1
- pax-cdi installs DeltaSpike 1.3.1
- ... therefore a unresolved dependency error occurs if all that is done is:

  ```
  feature:install pax-cdi pax-cdi-weld camel-cdi
  ```

Similar issues exist with newer versions of Camel as well.

Note, too, that even with the inclusion of updated DeltaSpike libraries, errors occur with pax-cdi 1.0.0.RC1, possibly due to an issue with Blueprint proxies.

Therefore, these instructions install pax-cdi 1.0.0.RC2 and the latest DeltaSpike 1.7.2, along with camel-cdi (2.16.4 for ServiceMix 7.0.0 and 2.18.2 for Karaf 4.1.0).

### To install and run in ServiceMix 7.0.0 (Karaf 4.0.8, Camel 2.16.4)

Start ServiceMix, connect to Karaf Console and install:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/1.0.0.RC2/xml/features
install mvn:org.apache.deltaspike.core/deltaspike-core-api/1.7.2
install mvn:org.apache.deltaspike.core/deltaspike-core-impl/1.7.2
feature:install pax-cdi/1.0.0.RC2
feature:install pax-cdi-weld/1.0.0.RC2
feature:install camel-cdi
install -s mvn:com.omniprise.demo/camel-osgi-cdi/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

### To install and run in a plain jane Karaf 4.x environment (Camel 2.18.2)

Start Karaf, connect to Karaf Console and install:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.18.2/xml/features
feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/1.0.0.RC2/xml/features
install mvn:org.apache.deltaspike.core/deltaspike-core-api/1.7.2
install mvn:org.apache.deltaspike.core/deltaspike-core-impl/1.7.2
feature:install pax-cdi/1.0.0.RC2
feature:install pax-cdi-weld/1.0.0.RC2
feature:install camel/2.18.2
feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2
feature:install camel-cdi/2.18.2
install -s mvn:com.omniprise.demo/camel-osgi-cdi/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

In both cases, the packages are all installed and listed as running, but the Camel Context isn't started:

```
70 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.RC2      | OPS4J Pax CDI Bean Bundle API
71 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.RC2      | OPS4J Pax CDI Extender for Bean Bundles
72 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.RC2      | OPS4J Pax CDI Portable Extension for OSGi
73 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.RC2      | OPS4J Pax CDI Service Provider Interface
74 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.RC2      | OPS4J Pax CDI Weld Adapter
... content removed for brevity
83 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.2         | camel-cdi
... content removed for brevity
92 | Active    |  80 | 1.8.1          | OPS4J Pax Swissbox :: Tracker
93 | Active    |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Camel CDI OSGi Demo
addmin@root()> camel:context-list
addmin@root()>
```

The is only one error in the log associated with camel-cdi installing pax-cdi 1.0.0.RC1 even though pax-cdi 1.0.0.RC2 is already present, and therefore a CDI provider is already registered.  At the end of the log, it is clear that the CDI binding is starting up, but there is no Context created, and the Route isn't producing messages - there's nothing indicating there was a problem finding the RouteBuilder or starting it:

```
2017-03-08T15:50:24,568 | INFO  | pipe-feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2 | CdiExtender                      | 71 - org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender - 1.0.0.RC2 | creating CDI container for bean bundle camel-osgi-cdi [93] with extension bundles [org.apache.camel.camel-cdi [83]]
2017-03-08T15:50:24,575 | INFO  | pipe-feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2 | AbstractCdiContainer             | 73 - org.ops4j.pax.cdi.spi - 1.0.0.RC2 | Starting CDI container for bundle camel-osgi-cdi [93]
2017-03-08T15:50:24,598 | INFO  | pipe-feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2 | Version                          | 69 - org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle - 2.3.5.Final | WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
2017-03-08T15:50:24,745 | INFO  | pipe-feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2 | Bootstrap                        | 69 - org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle - 2.3.5.Final | WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
2017-03-08T15:50:24,810 | WARN  | pipe-feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2 | Interceptor                      | 69 - org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle - 2.3.5.Final | WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2017-03-08T15:50:24,811 | WARN  | pipe-feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2 | Interceptor                      | 69 - org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle - 2.3.5.Final | WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2017-03-08T15:50:24,938 | INFO  | pipe-feature:install camel-blueprint/2.18.2 | Event                            | 69 - org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle - 2.3.5.Final | WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<?>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
```

### Source Code

There's all of two files in my very simple project the POM and the Class.  The pom.xml is in the project root folder:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.omniprise.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-osgi-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Camel CDI OSGi Demo</name>
  <description>Deploys simple routes using Camel Java DSL in ServiceMix OSGi Karaf container using CDI</description>

  <packaging>bundle</packaging>

  <properties>
    <default.encoding>UTF-8</default.encoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>${default.encoding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${default.encoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <slf4j.version-range>[1.7.2,1.8)</slf4j.version-range>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <!-- Maven Plugins -->
    <maven-bundle-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-bundle-plugin.version>
    <maven-bundle-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-bundle-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.encoding>${default.encoding}</maven-resources-plugin.encoding>
    <depends-maven-plugin.version>1.3.1</depends-maven-plugin.version>
    <!-- Tools -->
    <!-- camel.version>2.16.4</camel.version -->
    <camel.version>2.18.2</camel.version>
    <!-- camel-cdi.version>2.16.4</camel-cdi.version -->
    <camel-cdi.version>2.18.2</camel-cdi.version>
    <cdi-api.version>1.2</cdi-api.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>${cdi-api.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-cdi</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-cdi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version-range}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version-range}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>${maven-resources-plugin.encoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>depends-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${depends-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-depends-file</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-depends-file</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <remoteOBR />
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Private-Package></Private-Package>
            <Export-Package>com.omniprise.demo.cdi.builder</Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
            <Require-Capability>
              osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=pax.cdi)",
              org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extension; filter:="(extension=camel-cdi-extension)"
            </Require-Capability>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The DemoRouteBuilder.java is in src/main/java/com/omniprise/demo/cdi/builder

```
package com.omniprise.demo.cdi.builder;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.cdi.ContextName;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

//@ContextName("com.omniprise.demo.cdi.context")
public class DemoRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoRouteBuilder.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        log.info("Starting demo CDI route");
        from("timer://cdiTimer?period=5000")
          .routeId("com.omniprise.demo.cdi.route")
          .to("log:com.omniprise.demo.cdi.context")
          .to("mock:end");
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why the the DemoRouteBuilder class isn't getting called by the CDI infrastructure, which is supposed to find all RouteBuilder instances and trigger them.

Comment: So, I "solved" this, but it led to an additional question.  The problem was that I was missing a "beans.xml" document in META-INF.  The content of the beans.xml is nothing more than **<beans.>**, but apparently that's what's required to trigger the RouteBuilder.  That, in turn, implies that the CDI initiator is bound to the Spring initiator.  I tried a "blueprint.xml" in OSGI-INF/blueprint, but that didn't cause the RouteBuilder to Trigger.  Can anyone add insight on this?  I generally avoid Spring in OSGi because it "doesn't play well" in OSGi due to classloader behavior.

Comment: Well, dang.  The Spring initiator doesn't come into play - it looks for XML documents in META-INF/spring rather than META-INF itself.  The CDI specification requires META-INF/beans.xml to be present.  See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html.  So, how do I mark my own question answered with "Doh!"